# Laravel post route with url parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'm facing a big wall of larval routing and I can't seem to find a solution

I have this form in a view template

```
<form url="/request/{{$equipment->url}}" method="POST">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="mt10">Start Date:</div>
                            <input type="date" required name="starting_date" value="" placeholder="From" class="request-input request-date mb10">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="mt10">End Date:</div>
                            <input type="date" required name="ending_date" value="" placeholder="To" class="request-input request-date mb10">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="mt10">Quantity</div>
                            <input type="number" required name="quantity" value="" placeholder="Quantity" class="request-input mb10">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="mt10">Voltage</div>
                            <input type="number" required name="voltage" value="" placeholder="Voltage" class="request-input mb10">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="mt10">Param 1</div>
                            <input type="text" required name="param_1" value="" placeholder="Parameter" class="request-input mb10">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="mt10">Param 2</div>
                            <input type="text" required name="param_2" value="" placeholder="Parameter" class="request-input mb10">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <button class="btn btn-block button-orange">Get quotes now</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

and this is the corresponding routes

```
Route::group([ 'middleware' => 'rental'], function(){
 Route::get('/my-requests/{readby_url}', 'PagesController@requests');
 Route::post('/request/{equipment_url}', 'PagesController@request');
 Route::post('/request/create', 'RequestsController@create');
 Route::post('/request/accept', 'RequestsController@accept');
});
```

My issue is with `Route::post('/request/{equipment_url}', 'PagesController@request');`
 as it seems to not accept url parameters when the method is set to post.

i.e it throws the error

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 201:
in RouteCollection.php line 201
at RouteCollection->methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 188
at RouteCollection->getRouteForMethods(object(Request), array('GET', 'HEAD')) in RouteCollection.php line 140
at RouteCollection->match(object(Request)) in Router.php line 746
at Router->findRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 655
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 631
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 237
```

I want to pass a parameter and post data at the same time.

Is there a way to make this work? I've been told that Route::post handles GET as well but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with Laravel

```
<form url="/request/{{$equipment->url}}" method="POST">
```

replace `url` with `action`

```
<form action="/request/{{$equipment->url}}" method="POST">
```

Comment: What are the odds that Jad answered Jad the same day this question was posted

Comment: A jadzillion to 1.

Comment: what are the odds that I read this comment and upvoted it and then came back 
a year later and tried to upvote it again, only to realise the arrow is orange because I already upvoted it

Answer (score 5):

The HTTP POST verb doesn't accept parameters from the URL like GET, it accepts them from the Body of the HTTP POST. To fetch the post parameters you use the code below:

In routes.php:

```
Route::post('/request', 'PagesController@request');
```

and in your PagesController access the form input using one of the input methods such as below

```
public function request() 
{
    return Input::get('equipment_url');
}
```

Comment: The thing is I want the url to change and show the equipment_url, that's why I'm using route parameters

Comment: @JadSalhani then you will have to use GET

Comment: What's the motivation for this? In my case, passing parameter as a part of URL would make things *much* more convenient :(

Comment: I think this answer is missing the point. Yes, POST doesn't accept QUERY STRING params, but it does accept URI segments, and that's what the routes the OP posted are using.

Answer (score 5):

You can not send get parameters to post route.

**But you can achieve that by a simple trick, just pass your value ({{$equipment->url}}) in form's hidden filed or in session.**

For Example:

**html**

```
<form url="test/{{$equipment->url}}" method="POST">
    {{Input::hidden('name-of-field', $equipment->url)
    <div class="row">
        .......
    </div>
</form>
```

**route**

```
Route::post('test/{any-variable}', ['as' => 'test', 'uses' => 'TestController@test']);
```

**controller**

```
public function test()
{
    echo "<pre>";
    dd(Input::all());
}
```

**result**

```
array(1) {
           ["name-of-field"]=>
            string(5) "your value here"
          }
```

Comment: I think this answer is missing the point, too. You can not send get parameters (QUERY STRING) with a POST, but the routes the OP posted are using URI segments. Laravel resolves them nicely so I don't see any problem.