# Laravel form action parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to call a controller method from a form object, to increment a given item.

The problem is that when adding the parameter, the form action will add a question mark, instead of a slash.

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost/admin/pages?1">
```

How am I to define the parameter?

```
{!! Form::open([
    'action'=>['Admin\\PagesController@increment', $item->id],
    'style' => 'display:inline'
]) !!}
    {!! Form::submit('Move Up', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs']) !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: Did you try `Admin\PagesController@increment`?

Answer (score 5):

In you code sample, you are sending the item id as a HTTP GET parameter. You can access the item id in your controller by giving a name to the parameter as follows.

```
{!! Form::open([
    'action'=>['Admin\\PagesController@increment','itemId='.$item->id],
    'style' => 'display:inline'
]) !!}
```

Then access the item id in your controller by

```
Input:get('itemId')
```

Comment: Using the first option i get this error: Action App\Http\Controllers\/admin/pages/<?php echo e($item->id); ?> not defined

Second options gives me an ErrorException: Array to string conversion

Comment: @Zalon it seems that you cannot pass parameters with post requests. So you need to choose the second method. I edited the code. Refer this answer: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31872422/laravel-post-route-with-url-parameters/31873302#31873302

Comment: I played around with it a bit, I ended up getting it to work by using: 'url' => ['admin/pages/'.$item->id.'/increment'], instead of action. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Your function shhould looks like this

```
public function increment($id) 
    {
        //your code;
    }
```

And your route should have id in it with post request

```
Route::post('increment/{id}','PagesController@increment');
```